# Iterate 2D arrays and assignment to variables of function in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration, variable-assignment

I am new to Python. I have a 2D array (10,4) and need to iterate array elements by assigning four values of each row to four variables of function (x1, x2, x3, x4), and return function output. Please have a look at my code and give me suitable suggestions. Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nv = 4              
lb = [0, 0, 0, 0]
ub = [20, 17, 17, 15]
n = 10             

def random_population(nv,n,lb,ub):
    pop = np.zeros((n, nv)) 
    for i in range(n):
        pop[i,:] = np.random.uniform(lb,ub)
    return pop

population = random_population(nv, n, lb, ub)

i = 0 #row number
j = 0 # col number

rows = population.shape[0]
cols = population.shape[1]

x1 = population[i][j]
x2 = population[i][j+1]
x3 = population[i][j+2]
x4 = population[i][j+3]

def test(x1, x2, x3, x4):   
##Assignment statement
    y = x1+x2+x3+x4         
    return y
test(x1, x2, x3, x4)
```

Comment: `test(*tuple(np.random.uniform(lb, ub, size=(n, len(lb))).T))`

Comment: In a few weeks time you will want to have more meaningful names for the variables. Maybe `population_size`, `num_features`, `lower_bounds`, and `upper_bounds`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear, but if I got the goal correctly and the author needs **just iterating** based on the title (*instead of vectorizing as mentioned by **Michael Szczesny**
in the comments*), the following loop will put each row of *the population array* into *the test function*:

```
for row in population:
    x1, x2, x3, x4 = row
    test(x1, x2, x3, x4)
```

or

```
for row in population:
    test(*row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Python star expression to pass an array as a list of arguments to your test function.

```
test(*population[i])

// instead of
x1 = population[i][j]
x2 = population[i][j+1]
x3 = population[i][j+2]
x4 = population[i][j+3]
test(x1, x2, x3, x4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can just give your function numpy arrays and since addition between them is defined as element-wise addition it does what you want. So you first extract columns out of your array like this

```
population[:,0], population[:,1], ...
```

then

```
test(population[:,0],population[:,1],population[:,2],population[:,3])
```

gives you an array and the first value agrees with

```
test(x1, x2, x3, x4).
```